# What is the best way to rearrange checkboxex in a .Net WinForm custom control?

Tags: c#

I have a custom control in which I add checkboxes.

I want to rearrange the checkboxes when i check them, I mean the selected ones should

appear on top of the control.

Please suggest an efficient way to do it ?

Comment: Is this a WinForms control? WPF? ASP.NET Web Control?

Comment: You don't think this could be confusing to your user? If they click a checkbox and have the box they just click get replaced by something else? Maybe they ignore the text and think their click didn't work. Maybe they just get annoyed at seeing controls jump around. Etc.

Comment: I don't want to discourage...but that would be a terrible User Experience. Checkboxes would be bouncing all over the place every time one gets checked/unchecked.

Comment: you can set a timer an take the cb slowly up or down one row at a time

Comment: Depends on the application, guys... a shopping list where when you check an item it is get to the bottom (or top) of the stack is a perfectly reasonable scenario to move the checkboxes around, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put then in a FlowLayoutPanel.  Shift+Click to select them all and assign the CheckedChanged event handler.  Make it look like this:

```
    private void checkBoxes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var box = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (box.Checked) box.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(box, 0);
    }
```

Try it out, I think you'll find it as disorienting as your user will.

Answer (score 0):

put them in a Dictionary, and sort it according to key.
when you change the check, make sure to make an event to change the value and resort yourself, with bubble sort while replacing each two's positions.